# How to use "checked=true" with Primefaces's SelectOneRadio?

Tags: jquery, primefaces, radio-button, checked

I would like to use jQuery to change the checked status of the radio button of Primefaces.
But the only thing I am able to set is: `disabled=false/true`.

I think it is possible to do this with jQuery, but I cannot see the dot inside the Radio-Button, probably because Primefaces is using an image for this.

Does someone know how to change the `checked`-status of a radiobutton within Primefaces? Additionally I have to be able to fetch the state of the single radiobutton.

Comment: are you sure you would go with radio buttons, and not checkboxes? (you can style them like radio)... Also: put some example code. How many options your checkbox has?

Answer (score 1):

SelectOneRadio has no checked attribute. [see documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/index.html?org/primefaces/component/selectoneradio/SelectOneRadio.PropertyKeys.html).

You seem to be [looking for a SelectBooleanCheckbox](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/component/selectbooleancheckbox/SelectBooleanCheckbox.html), or for how to [find the checked value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941461/how-to-get-the-value-of-checkbox) of a SelectBooleanCheckbox

You can get the value of the SelectOneRadio via javascript using the [solution posted in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385591/how-to-get-the-selected-option-from-hselectoneradio-using-javascript). It can be modified easily to get the selected value of the radio buttons.

### But the real answer to your question is:

There is no such thing as a checked attribute to the `<p:selectOneRadio>` element. If you want one, you will have to extend the component classes.